# OpenStack Swift swiftclient - How to write and read {pickle files

Tags: python, pickle, openstack

I am stuck. Read all the doc I can find and can't figure out how to write and read pickle files using swiftclient. I *think* I'm successfully writing the pickle file into Swift but even if that's the case I can't figure out the syntax for getting it out and un-pickling it. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be asking a question about Python programming. May I suggest you share the relevant parts of your program and what you want to achieve? Swift doesn't care for the format of the data that you upload and download; pickle files, text file, videos, there is no difference.

Comment: This is my first experience with Swift, and I haven't used pickle much either. Have only encountered issues with successfully pickling class instances and persisting them on Swift - everything else works fine. I'm pretty sure at this point that it's a pickle issue not a Swift one, and I'm zeroing in on a solution. I'll post another comment to confirm that.

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. What exactly are you doing, what exactly happens, and what exactly do you expect to happen.

Comment: First I'm happy to report that the issue has been resolved. Cause was my inexperience with the three elements and the appropriate syntax: 1. Swift, 2. Python swiftclient, and 3. pickling and un-pickling a class instance.

As for what I needed to do:
1. Pickle a class instance object.
2. Pass the pickle file to my swift instance and save it in the specified container
3. Retrieve the pickle file from the swift container.
4. Un-pickle the class instance
5. Do the same sort of thing with the un-pickled class that I would do with the class before it was persisted to Swift.

Comment: Documenting all that with sample code might make an interesting Medium article.

Comment: @GDB How did you resolve it?

Comment: Pivoted to Redis, not for the pickle issue though, just a better platform for our use case and better internal support. As I recall the approach that finally worked was writing the pickle file to a tmp file and reading it from there.